# Representation without " '' " in lists with atomic_list_concat/3 with operator defined (~)

Tags: prolog

I defined the (~) operator in this way:

```
:-op(190,fx,~).
```

my problem is in the query:

```
 ?- atomic_list_concat(L,',','~t1,tren,casa').
 L = ['~t1', tren, casa].

 [debug]  ?- atomic_list_concat(L,',','~t1,tren,~casa').
 L = ['~t1', tren, '~casa'].
```

how can I do to remove those " '' " in the elements that have the operator I defined? What I need to get is

```
L = [~t1, tren, ~casa]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make `~t1` without bracket it should be a term. `atomic_list_concat/2` creates list of atoms not terms. We can make terms by `atom_to_term/3`:

```
:- op(190, fx, ~).

make_terms([A], [B]):- atom_to_term(A,B,_).
make_terms([A|T], [B|RT]):- atom_to_term(A,B,_), make_terms(T, RT).
```

And finally:

```
atomic_list_concat(L,',','~a,tren,~casa'), make_terms(L, Z).
```